# Mounting Sharepoint on Ubuntu as a Remote Network Location

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, webdav

For the Office 2016 Sharepoint I would like to mount it to Ubuntu as a remote Network Location.

But following are the limitation

1. WebDAV is disabled in the sharepoint. Also autoversioning is disabled.
2. FTP is not available as a protocol. Only HTTPS is the protocol.
3. SMB address is also not available. Not sure if Sharepoint can be mounted as a smb drive as well.

This is how it works on windows.

1. Sharepoint is mapped as a remote network location on the windows
2. Every boot up time. Credentials need to be put into the location.

Is there any way to do the same in ubuntu? WebDAV method will not work as it is disabled.

What should i look into that would possibly solve this problem or give a hint to a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is mounted under Windows, then WebDAV is enabled; this is the protocol used to mount SharePoint sites as volumes. Use WebDAV.

Comment: Took some time to implement the dav in ubuntu. But got it working with sharepoint. Yes you are right. WebDAV is there only autoversioning is not allowed. To perform autoversioning, i believe certain steps need to be taken before it can be automatically versioned... Probably checkout or checkin activities.. Something like that.... But really thanks for this information... This was something i was not aware of.